# How to determine C code is compiled for Android/NDK or iOS

Tags: android, c, ios, portability, android-ndk

I am reusing a legacy C library in an iOS app and in an Android app. I want to customize some macro definitions (e.g. for logging). Are there standard defines to check for (using #ifdef) whether the code is being compiled for iOS or Android/NDK?

Comment: Please don't use `#ifdef` for this. Write portable code and put platform-specific issues in per-platform modules with a common interface.

Comment: Put in the different module, compile each using different include path

Comment: Generally, but one must balance the magnitude of the difference with the desirability of keeping functionality organized.  Over use of abstraction can just as easily make code unreadable as under use.  If I had a large block of code that was identical except for one inherited linux-vs-bsd difference in a unix system call, I'd probably #ifdef it with a comment right there, rather than invent a new personal concept of portable unix and bury the implementation in inline functions pulled from some header file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`__ANDROID__` or `ANDROID` for Android (compilation with the NDK)
and `__APPLE__` on Apple platforms (iOS or OSX)

Comment: It is ANDROID without underscores. Thank you.

Comment: No, it is `__ANDROID__` **with** underscores. Quoting [David Turner](http://markmail.org/message/5ekhfztchs45lz3n): “I would recommend defining `__ANDROID__` explicitely for now, it should be the only thing that NDK users should be testing again”.

Answer (score 1):

you should consider creating two separate projects for those platforms with separate output/bin directories but shared source code. Then you just set some define in project properties for android and ios so you can recognize it when compiling